# malloc() returns a pointer to char full of random characters

Tags: c

I have a simple program in C and I'm trying to make the intersection of two sets(no duplicates). And there are a bunch of characters printed after my intersection result.

It's some how related to the fact that strlen(scommon) = 14 instead of 2(sizeof(char) * strlen(smin) = 1 *2).

Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* intersection(char *s1, char *s2);

int main(void){


   printf("intersection = %s\n", intersection("ag", "cg"));

   return 0;
}

char* intersection(char *s1, char *s2){
    int i, j;
    char *smin, *scommon;   

    if(strlen(s1) < strlen(s2)){    
        smin = s1; 
        s1 = s2;
    }else{      
        smin = s2;      
    }

    scommon = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(smin));   

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(smin); i++){

        for(j = 0; j < strlen(s1); j++){

            if(smin[i] == s1[j]){

                scommon[i] = smin[i];

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("final length = %d\n", strlen(scommon));     
    return scommon;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not the fault of `malloc`. It's the fault of `intersection`.

Comment: Yep, the contents of a `malloc`ed buffer are unspecified. What's your question?

Comment: Why oh why say something verbose as `(char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(smin))` when it is just `malloc(strlen(smin))`?

Comment: Please, for the _umpteenth_ time, don't cast the return value of a `malloc` call in C. A void pointer needs no cast... casting is, by many, considered to be bad practice. Also read the man for `malloc`: the memory is _not_ initialized, using `calloc` would return a clean chunk of memory. Lastly: what on _earth_ are you trying to do? `memset` or `memcpy` can help here

Comment: How can I avoid the error given by the lack of the cast (char*) then?

Comment: you can't get an error, a warning, possibly, but just use a better compiler, that compiles C as C, and not C++ (C++ _does_ require the cast)

Comment: I get a syntax error.

Comment: I use Microsoft Visual Studio. I don't know how to change the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scommon = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(smin));
```

This doesn't add an extra byte to accommodate a null terminator for the string, and `intersection` doesn't add a null terminator after the loop completes.

You could just change it to:

```
scommon = malloc(strlen(smin)+1);
memset( scommon, 0, strlen(smin)+1 );
```

Or add the terminating zero when the loop completes and you know where you want to put it.

Or just use `calloc` which will initialize the buffer for you:

```
scommon = calloc(strlen(smin)+1, sizeof(char));
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `calloc`, it saves you an extra `strlen` call: `scommon = calloc(strlen(smin) + 1, sizeof(*scommon));` does exactly the same thing

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem no good reason other than I didn't think of it. I just had my mind wrapped around the `malloc` in the OP's example code. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to null-terminate your scommon string.  You have to add a '\0' after the last
character, or the strlen and printf will just keep going until they hit a null character, or crash the program.

In general, you cannot count on malloc to return buffers with all 0's in them.  If you want the buffer to be 'empty' you have to initialize it yourself, or use `calloc` instead

Comment: I tried that. The length of scommon is 14 before entering the for loop. And how can you know where to add the '\0' character if its length is bigger from the start?

Comment: At the end of the loop, `scommon[i] = '\0';`

Comment: @ChrisJ.Kiick: No need if you're using `calloc`, as you should when dealing with strings...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the main issue is (apart from the null termination issue):

```
scommon[i] = smin[i];
```

If there is not an intersection then `i` will be increased none-the-less. And according to the `malloc` function description:

> The content of the newly allocated block of memory is not initialized, remaining with indeterminate values.

You should use a separate counter for `scommon`. And add a null termination character or save the length of the string somewhere.